# Сложное предложение

Tags: запятые, прямая-речь

### Современники вспоминали: Горькому, когда он читал пьесу вслух, лучше всего удавалась именно роль Луки.

Предложение взято из Тотального диктанта этого года. Согласно эталонному тексту, здесь обычное БСП, но можно ли было оформить данную конструкцию как прямую речь?

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему, по-вашему, именно такой вариант принят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Какая же это прямая речь, кому она принадлежит? Сразу всем современникам?!

Comment: Можно ли это предложение приписать к данному правилу: "Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь в следующих случаях:

1) если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или если приводится общеизвестная пословица, поговорка".

Comment: Да, первая часть как раз про этот случай.